# R rename dataset

Tags: r, user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm creating a GUI using Tcltk package and I would like to know if there is a way to rename the dataset I'm importing. Basically, I would like the user to choose a name for the dataset he imports, but my code below is not giving me that. What Im trying to do is the same concept as RStudio does when importing a file.
Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thank you in advance!

```
require(tcltk)
tt <- tktoplevel()
tkwm.title(tt, "Read Text Data")
dsName <- tclVar("Dataset")
entry.Name <-tkentry(tt,width="20",textvariable=dsName)
entry.box <- tklabel(tt,text="Please enter dataset name:")
tkgrid(entry.box, entry.Name)
tkgrid(tklabel(tt,text=""))

onOk <- function() 
{
  myval <- tclvalue(tkgetOpenFile())
  myData <<- read.table(myval, header=TRUE, sep=",", dec = ".")
} 

OK.but <- tkbutton(tt,text="  Import  ",command=onOk)
Qt.but <- tkbutton(tt,text="  Cancel  ",command=function()tkdestroy(tt))
tkgrid(OK.but, Qt.but)
tkfocus(tt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this line:

```
myData <<- read.table(myval, header=TRUE, sep=",", dec = ".")
```

Try something like:

```
myData <- read.table(myval, header=TRUE, sep=",", dec = ".")
assign(tclvalue(dsName), myData, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Though you may want to make `envir = .GlobalEnv` something else (if you're planning to put this on CRAN, you can't assign to the global environment in this way and instead have to use a user-created environment).

Some other notes:

1. You probably want a `tkdestroy` call at the end of your `onOK` function.
2. You might want to add a logical to check whether the user has actually supplied a name for the dataset when they press OK.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas for the answer and advice! I will try that!

Comment: The procedure you showed me worked pretty well, thank you again. But now, I have another question. The reason why i wanted this is because of a UI i'm creating, so another functions will be called, such as the summary, for example. The problem now is because the user can choose their dataset name, now my summary function doesn't work anymore, because it was "set" to another name. How can I resolve that?

Comment: Take a look at `get`, for something like `summary(get(tclvalue(dsName)))`.